# Getting error Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails even setting ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Tags: mysql

I've checked all question dependent to this error but couldn't find my answer

This is my EER diagram [EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgFUN.png)
I insert a row in Sales For example like this( SellerFId=1 , GoodFId=1, CustomerFId=1) So I wanna be able to delete the Seller Or Good Or Customer From Their own Table So that inserted Row in Sales Still preserved I used This Foreign Constrain between Sales and Other tables

```
 ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

But when I Delete Seller Or Good Or Customer From Their own Tables The mysql doesn't allow me and give me this error

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`newmobarakkabul`.`sales`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Sellers_has_Goods_has_Customers_Sellers1` FOREIGN KEY (`SellerFId`) REFERENCES `staffs` (`StaffId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

So Specifically My question is this do I really need to have the foreign key constraint between Sales and Other tables or not (if not so what is this query for  "ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION"
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, [`NO ACTION` is an equivalent of `RESTRICT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to RESTRICT. The MySQL Server rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table. Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO ACTION is a deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are checked immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.

and also

> RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table. Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON DELETE or ON UPDATE clause.

As for your last question, whether you really need such constraint is to be determined based on the specs of your application.

Comment: So In this diagram If I Drop the Foreign Key Constrains, Does it really matter( I mean will I face to any Problem) 
My demand is to preserve the record in 'Sales' If I delete Them from Parent tables

Comment: If you delete the constraint, the database will no longer enforce data integrity.. More than that I cannot say, since I do not really know your app.

Comment: As I posted the Diagram Picture The `Sales` Table Contains The Record Of (The seller from Staffs Table Sells Goods From `Goods` Table To a customer From `Customers` Table)
So If any row from (Staffs, Customers, Goods) Gets Deleted Their Record Should be Preserved to the Sales Table

Comment: Seeing an EER diagram doesn't mean I know your app... Anyway, removing constraints between those tables means that the database will no longer do cascade delete or, in your case, deletion blocking; it'll just let you delete the row and have "orphaned" rows in the Sales table, as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MatteoTassinari